# Windows CE HP iPAQ - USB Stick

Tags: linux, windows-ce, usb-drive, activesync

Hi all Windows CE developer,

is there an option that a Windows CE device (HP iPAQ) acts as a "normal" USB-drive if it will connected to PC. In this case I have an linux (embedded) device and I have to copy some files from iPAQ every few seconds.
I can not change or recompile any CE Firmware from this devices. The best would be a program to get the USB-drive possibility.
I tryed an CE-ftp server but it did not work because of the "RNDIS" stuff - TCP/IP is missing.

The ActiveSync did not work with linux. I only could get an usb-ethernet connection with RNDIS but without the communication library it makes no sense. "Synce" did not work as well some derivates.

thanks
regards
ferdl

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Internet of Things Stack Exchange](https://iot.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I think you are not right, because the "Internet of Things" is not specific enough and looks like a "skiny blabla" forum - sorry to say that. In my opinion this question can better answer a "pro" developer who has "deep" expirience about the described system (windows ce).

Comment: @Ferdl Meanwhile, you can post to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winembplatdev/threads It's MSDN forum for WinCE. There are few more developers answering there. BTW, the USB drive functionality is highly dependent on the BSP. I mean, the functionality should be supported by the WinCE BSP (firmware) on the device. So it would be good to contact the firmware vendor and ask about the support. And yes, WinCE supports USB Mass storage functionality. But as I mentioned, it depends on BSP (firmware).